# Users cannot view a customized List (needs add and customize page permissions)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, custom-list, fieldcustomizers

I took over a SharePoint site that has customized code to display a list.  About two weeks ago, I changed all the groups from "Edit, Contribute, Read, and Approve" permissions to "Contribute" because I felt that it was too much permissions for a users.  Well users started to get the

***"You do not have the Add and Customize Page permissions, which is required to edit the contents of this web part."***

error and they were not able to view the list.  I put the "Edit, Contribute, Read, and Approve" back and all is well.  Today, the error returned: users no longer able to view the list and they receive the ***"You do not have the Add and Customize Page permissions..."*** again.

Is this a web part issue?  The web part is a content editor that is linked to a text file with JavaScript code.

Comment: Can you check the javascript code? In code is there anything related to permissions or group? Can you please add the javascript code to your question if possible?

Comment: @GaneshSanap, I'll have to change up the wording a bit.  I'll add it to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the "Contribute" permission level and tick additional "Add and Customize Pages"[image] site permission, then give a new name and save. Then grant the user with this new permission level, check if the issue exists.

Comment: thanks, I'm sure this will work.  I don't have access to create new permissions however, I did give a user Full Control to test this and it worked.  The thing is, it all of a sudden did this.  So there must have been some maintenance or new securities features or some other random anomaly that made this no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it wasn't a permissions issue at all.  It was a coding issue.  Basically the code had an incorrect spelling of a field name.  Again, that particular line of code was showing the access/permissions to a web part error message.  Everything else was showing fine.  So once that was corrected, it worked.